# C Programming - Max steps in array, shows more than max

Tags: c, arrays, max

I am writing a piece of software and I got a problem.
What I try to do, is to go through an array, of which elements can be only 1 or 0, and write out the maximum steps that somebody can perform from a given point in the array.
The rule is that people can step 1 or more steps only if it's the same number. Let's say my array looks like this:
1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0
I start from the beginning, I should only be able to step once, as after 1 is 0, and I can't change numbers while stepping, only when my turn comes again. So if I would start from second element, I could step 1, or 4 steps. Now, I want to write out the maximum amount of steps the current player can step, but for some reason, it shows the max step + 1.

Each variable is of int type. 
tomb = array, j,max_lepes initializes with 0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int tomb[200]={1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1}; // Fo tomb
    int max_lepes,akt_pos,j,i,game_type=0;

    printf("Valasszon jatek tipust (1 Ember vs Szamitogep, 2 Ember vs Ember): ");
    scanf("%d", &game_type);


    if (game_type==1) {


    } else if (game_type==2) {
        // Aktualis tomb kiirasa
        printf("\nAz aktualis szin tomb: ");
        for (i=0; i<11; ++i) {
            printf("%d ", tomb[i]);
        }
        i==0;
        // Max lepesek kiirasa
        max_lepes == 0;
        akt_pos == 0;
        for (j=0; j<11; ++j) {
            if (tomb[j]==tomb[j+1]) {
                max_lepes=max_lepes+1;
            } else {
                printf("\nMaximum lepesek szama= %d", max_lepes);
                break;
            }
        }

    } else {
        printf("Rosz szamot irt be, kerem irjon be 1-et vagy 2-et.");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is going to print 0 and then stop.

Comment: It actually writes out 2 for some reason.

Comment: Not the code you have given us ... not if your array starts with 1 and 0. You need to post the actual program you're running.

Comment: `max_lepes` should be initialized with 1 not 0

Comment: @CoolGuy That's only one of the bugs. This code only prints one number, and `j<11` doesn't match the OP's example array.

Comment: It doesn't matter if I initialize with 0 or 1, it still says 2

Comment: what do you expect the result of `1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0` to be?

Comment: If I start from the beginning, then 1, as then the number changes, and the maximum number of steps is 1

Comment: So, do you want all possible cases?

Comment: My answer gives your typo. The other answers fix your other bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
max_lepes == 0;
akt_pos == 0;
```

Should be

```
max_lepes = 0;
akt_pos = 0;
```

Comment: @Maniak You still have other bugs ... the value you print will be 1 too small, and you will only print a value for the first position.

Comment: I know, it was only for testing, I now initialized with 1 and made an actual position variable to hold the actual position and start the forloop from that value.

Answer (score 1):

```
        i==0;
        max_lepes == 0;
        akt_pos == 0;
```

These don't assign variables to 0.`==` is for comparison and `=` is for assignment. So change them to

```
        i=0;
        max_lepes = 1;// because max can be at least 1
        akt_pos = 0;
```